# Vuejs/Posgres - When clicked on button I want to save a value in db postgresql

Tags: postgresql, vue.js, axios, vuejs3

Hi so I have a view where I have a button , When it's clicked I want a value to be saved in the db . What I get now is nothing like I click on button but nothing happens .
Here's the code I have :

```
<a-button type="primary" class="mb-4 text-center mr-1 float-right"  @click="onSubmit">Confirm</a-button>
```

in my script I have:

```
   setup(){
const onSubmit = () => {
  
axios.post("/insertstatut/"+876,"added").then((res)=>{
    message.success(`statut ajouté`)
    router.push({ 
          path:'/cand',
        }).catch(error => {
      console.log('error', error);
    })
  } ,
  )
  }
  }
```

Please if u have any idea what I should do , do share thank you.

Comment: What browser console errors do you see?

Comment: I don't get an error, i actually think everything is wrong even from the query, i am absolutely lost I have no idea where to start or waht i should have

Comment: The code you're showing alone should yield an error in that it doesn't return `onSubmit`. Can you link to a codesandbox that reproduces the problem?

Comment: are you sure your problem has nothing to do with your server side?

Comment: You are not returning the `onSubmit` method in `setup`. Do `return {onSubmit}` at the end of `setup`

Comment: It was actually a problem with my server side I should of had an update query not insert and forgot to add the onSubmit in my return :) thnx for ur time

Answer (score 1):

you are using composition api feature setup in your vue code,
you need to return the methods or properties u wish to use in in your template.

```
setup () {
   return {
     onSubmit: () => {}, //some method u want to use later in template ,
     show: false, // or some property 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is how your component should look

```
<template>
  <a-button
    type="primary"
    class="mb-4
    text-center
    mr-1float-right"
    @click="onSubmit"
  >
    Confirm
  </a-button>
</template>
<script>
import AButton from './button-path/AButton.vue'
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  componets: { AButton },
  setup() {
    const onSubmit = () => {
      axios.post('/insertstatut/' + 876, 'added').then((res) => {
        message.success(`statut ajouté`)
        router
          .push({
            path: '/cand',
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log('error', error)
          })
      })
    }
    // Expose your constants/methods/functions
    return {
      onSubmit,
    }
  },
}
</script>
```